# Como imprimir um webview em uma impressora bluetooth?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que ele precisa imprimir o conteudo de uma webview , porém a impressora é bluetooth , poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Existe uma questão semelhante sobre o assunto nesse link aqui [how android use BlueTooth printer print the WebView content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155827/how-android-use-bluetooth-printer-print-the-webview-content) verifique se te ajuda.

Comment: Esse daí ele procura impressoras no Wifi, preciso que seja no bluetooth , obrigado pela força

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impressão em bluetooth no android não é uma coisa simples, nem tão pouco fácil de ser feito.

Vou deixar aqui um caminho para que possa atingir seu objetivo:

1. Existe uma [library](https://github.com/MFori/Android-Bluetooth-Printer) que faz a comunicação com o bluetooh diretamente já. Mas para curiosidade, você tem que listar os devices bluetooth e depois de achá-los, você tem que abrir um socket para ele e mandar a impressão. Essa library facilita todo esse trabalho.
2. Como uma página web é renderizada já, e como o interesse é imprimir ela formatada, não o código-fonte, você teria que gerar uma imagem deste html. Se utilizar. [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963109/7762411) do SOen vai te mostrar como fazer isso.
3. Depois de ter um snapshot da sua webview, você envia para a library em 1, chamando o método printImage(Bitmap).